# yathesis class, jury description

Tags: titlesec, yathesis

In the class yathesis,
How can we change the description of a jury:
% - « professor », « seniorresearcher », « mcf », « mcf* »,
%   « juniorresearcher », « juniorresearcher* » 
?
I want to specify another description...

Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by adding the following to preamble

```
\expression{professor}{french description 1}{english description 1}
\expression{mcf}{french description 2}{english description 2}
\expression{juniorresearcher}{french description 3}{english description 3}
```